# Parsing Eventlogs XML file to CSV in Python

Tags: python, xml, csv, event-log

I am working on a simple python script to extract certain data from an xml file. The xml contains windows events and eventid. Below I am showing the code. It is failing when it needs to extract the data, but it is creating the file but is empty.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("SecurityLog-rev2.xml")
root = tree.getroot() 

url = root[0].tag[:-len("Event")]
fieldnames = ['EventID']

with open ('event_log.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writecsv = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = fieldnames)
    writecsv.writeheader()

    for event in root:
        system = event.find(url + "System")
        output = {}
        fields = ['EventID']
   # for tag,att in fields:
   #     output[tag] = system.find(url + tag).attrib[att]

        if event.find(url + "EventData") != None:
            for data in event.find(url + "EventData"):
                name = data.attrib['Name']
                output[name] = data.text

        writecsv.writerow(output)
```

```
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}'/>
<EventID>4634</EventID>
<Version>0</Version><Level>0</Level><Task>12545</Task><Opcode>0</Opcode><Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2011-04-16T15:07:53.890625000Z'/>
<EventRecordID>1410962</EventRecordID><Correlation/><Execution ProcessID='452' ThreadID='3900'/><Channel>Security</Channel><Computer>DC01.AFC.com</Computer><Security/></System>
<EventData><Data Name='TargetUserSid'>S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610</Data>
<Data Name='TargetUserName'>grant.larson</Data>
<Data Name='TargetDomainName'>AFC</Data><Data Name='TargetLogonId'>0x3642df8</Data><Data Name='LogonType'>3</Data></EventData></Event>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but the website is not allowing me to enter the code. It is too long.

Comment: Create a small subset of this file. Make sure it is a **VALID** xml. Add it to the post.

Comment: I was able to add one single event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you would parse. Here is a solution for the Id and the events:

Your **XML File** provided above as Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'>
  <System>
    <Provider Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' Guid='{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}' />
    <EventID>4634</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12545</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime='2011-04-16T15:07:53.890625000Z' />
    <EventRecordID>1410962</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID='452' ThreadID='3900' />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>DC01.AFC.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name='TargetUserSid'>S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetUserName'>grant.larson</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetDomainName'>AFC</Data>
    <Data Name='TargetLogonId'>0x3642df8</Data>
    <Data Name='LogonType'>3</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The program code without regex for catching the namespace:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import csv

tree = ET.parse("SecurityLog-rev2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
ns = "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}"

data = []
for eventID in root.findall(".//"):
    
    if eventID.tag == f"{ns}System":
        for e_id in eventID.iter():
            if e_id.tag == f'{ns}EventID':
                row =  "EventID", e_id.text
                data.append(row)
    
    if eventID.tag == f"{ns}EventData":
        for attr in eventID.iter():
            if attr.tag == f'{ns}Data':
                #print(attr.attrib)
                row = attr.get('Name'), attr.text
                data.append(row)
                
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
df.to_csv('event_log.csv', index=False, header=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  0                                               1
0           EventID                                            4634
1     TargetUserSid  S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610
2    TargetUserName                                    grant.larson
3  TargetDomainName                                             AFC
4     TargetLogonId                                       0x3642df8
5         LogonType                                               3
```

The **CSV File** doesn't contain the index and header:

```
EventID,4634
TargetUserSid,S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610
TargetUserName,grant.larson
TargetDomainName,AFC
TargetLogonId,0x3642df8
LogonType,3
```

You can tanspose() the output:

```
df.T.to_csv('event_log.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Did you have to setup the environment before running the script?

Comment: I am getting this error.

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cyber-admin/Downloads/sample.py", line 8, in <module>
    ns = re.match(r'{.*}', root.tag).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
`````

Comment: It seems your regex expression have some trouble. Try to replace to: #ns = re.match(r'{.*}', root.tag).group(0)
#print(ns) to
`ns = "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}"`

Comment: I am using Windows 10.  The error keeps occurring.

````
    ns = re.match(r'{.*}', root.tag).group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
````

Comment: This couln't be the case, if you comment this line out with `#ns = re.match(r'{.*}', root.tag).group(0)`. You can also remove this line of code completly and write the line from my previous comment instead. Than you can also delete `import re`, because this is no longer in use,

Comment: I changed my answer above as suggested here in the comment. Have you the same XML snippet as you provided above?

Comment: This did the trick. How can I have each field to be a column? Now, the cvs is showing each event in vertical format.

Comment: see above, Please accept my answer.